# Python method or pre-existing module to access csv via headers instead of column ID's

Tags: python, csv

I am being forced to work a project off of CSV files instead of a database... irritating but true. I have no control of the organization which the CSV will come out in. I can reasonably guarantee that the names will be maintained in the CSV header.

I was just getting ready to write some code to return column id's on string matches, but was wondering if there was a module that might be able to do this for me?

```
e.g.
data = csv.csvRowData[5] becomes
data = csv.csvRowData[find_rowID('column_name')]
```

Forgive me if my code syntax is off, came from php. Will figure out how to make it work in the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `pandas` package, there is a powerful `read_csv` utility http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html

```
cat test.csv

date,value
2014,Hi
2015,Hello

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

This returns a `pandas.DataFrame` that does what you want (and a lot more, e.g. conversion of the data types on the columns), try it out on IPython:

```
In [5]: df['date']
Out[5]:
0    2014
1    2015
Name: date, dtype: int64

In [6]: df.columns
Out[6]: Index([u'date', u'value'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 0):

The python standard library includes the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv).

It provides the [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) class which will allow you to access a row's data by column header labels.

DictReader will take the first row in the CSV file to be the column headers then provide every subsequent row as a dict with the column labels as keys and the row's data as values.

For example if `people.csv` looked like this:

```
"First Name","Last Name"
Peter,Venkman
Egon,Spengler
```

You can use DictReader like this:

```
import csv

with open('people.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        print row["Last Name"]

# will output
Venkman
Spengler
```